# Unrecognized type or namespace in SSIS C# script

Tags: c#, ssis

I was trying to use regex to get a variable from a filename using a script task in SSIS.  I found the following bit of code, but several of the functions appear to be unrecognized:

```
List<string> filePatterns = null;
public void Main()
{
    filePatterns = new List<string>();
    filePatterns.Add("Folder1");
    filePatterns.Add("Folder2");

    string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(
        Dts.Variables["User::LoopFiles"].Value.ToString());

    Match match = Regex.Match(fileName, string.Join("|", 
        filePatterns.ToArray()));

    Dts.Variables["User::FolderName"].Value = match.Value;
    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

The List and Match both return

> The type or namespace name 'List' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Also, Path returns the name 'Path' does not exist in the current context.

I figure I'm missing a library of some sort, but I would like to know where to find it and how to get it referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The List is a Generic Collection and so you'll need to add a reference to the namespace [System.Collections.Generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic(v=vs.110).aspx)

Path is coming to you from the [System.IO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace so you'll need a reference to that as well.

Match is coming from the [System.Text.RegularExpressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions(v=vs.110).aspx)

There should be no need to add an explicit reference to the assemblies themselves though so you should need to add the following to the initial using statements.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Note that the Generics *isn't* available to the 2.0 framework (citation needed) so you'd need change the SSIS Script Task's project to use the 3.5 framework.